# how to open two or many popups with one javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

i'enter code here novice in javascript  i'm trying to make a popup but i have issue when opening these popups i don't find how to open these two divs with one javascript code
it open one not the other i tried many solutions i find in this website but it still doesn't word

here are my html css and javascript code

```js
 var modal = document.querySelector(".aaa");
        var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
        var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

        function toggleModal() {
            modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
        }

        function windowOnClick(event) {
            if (event.target === modal) {
                toggleModal();
            }
        }

        trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
        closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
        window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

```css
   .aaa {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            opacity: 0;
            visibility: hidden;
            transform: scale(1.1);
            transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
        }

        .modal-content {
            
            position:relative;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            background-color: white;
            padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
            width: 65%;
            height: 80%;
            border-radius: 0.5rem;
        }

        .close-button {
            float: right ;
            width: 1.5rem;
            line-height: 1.5rem;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 0.25rem;
            background-color: lightgray;
        }

        .close-button:hover {
            background-color: darkgray;
        }

        .show-modal {
            opacity: 1;
            visibility: visible;
            transform: scale(1.0);
            transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
        }
```

```html
    <button class="trigger">Click here to trigger the modal!</button>
    <div class="aaa">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
            <div>
                <h2>edddddddddddddd</h2>
               <p>hhhhhhhhhdefrfrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrghjuyhgt</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <button class="trigger">Click here to trigger the modal!</button>
    <div class="aaa">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
            <div>
                <h2>egtgttttttttgtg</h2>
               <p>55555555555555555555555555</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `querySelector` returns the first element that matches the specified selector, so that's why the first button works and opens the first modal

Answer (score 1):

It is because querySelector takes only the first .trigger

You should loop through all the elements using the ALL selector querySelectorAll() like :

```
var triggers = document.querySelectorAll(".trigger");

for( var i=0;i<triggers.length;i++){
     triggers[i].addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
}
```

Comment: but it still opening the same div

Comment: Why would you expect it to open a different div/modal?

Answer (score 0):

Writing an answer because I can't comment yet.

ortoDev is correct. To open different modals you need to use querySelectorAll on the modals as well.

Any time you query a css class you have to assume you will get an array because multiple components can have the same class.

`document.querySelector(".aaa"); == document.querySelectorAll(".aaa")[0];`